Anyway to use tensorflow's set_session on tensorflow 2.16
I have been completely lost on trying to import this set_session for a project. I have tried using:
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import set_session

and
from tensorflow.keras.backend import set_session`

(and numerous other variations)
Is all hope lost? I am using python 3.11.1, tensorflow 2.16.1 (which installs keras 3.3.3)

I was hoping to make this program as easy to run as possible but it seems like the only way may be to install an old version of tensorflow (which you can't do with pip)
set_session should work, and I have gotten it to work on older versions of tensorflow I would just like it to be friendly to download my program without going through that struggle. I also have it use this:
def get_session(gpu_fraction): #set GPU memory usage for TensorFlow
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = gpu_fraction
    return  tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)


Are you working in the notebook? How do you use Session in your code? It seems that Session is deprecated and it is recommended to rewrite the code without it.
If you are using gpus in the notebooks I think one of the options could be to use InteractiveSession:
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.2
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)

set_session(session)


I use session like this:
'return  tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config) '
'set_session(get_session(gpu_frac))'
I am not using notebook, I am working in a python file which runs a neural network model.
I will try your idea though

So, what happens when you run from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session and set_session(sess). What is the error?

I get ImportError: cannot import name 'set_session' from 'tensorflow.keras.backend'
I think I am forced to use an old version, using your technique I got past the error but then got a pretty nasty lr error :     raise ValueError(f"Argument(s) not recognized: {kwargs}")
ValueError: Argument(s) not recognized: {'lr': 0.0005000000237487257}
I assume this error is from the keras version

Keep in mind my code works perfectly using specific old tensorflow and python versions, in which I used from tensorflow.keras.backend import set_session.

I fixed my issue, not by changing any code. I realized I just had to adopt an older version in order to do anything with my model so I used:

python 3.7.16
tensorflow==2.5.0
keras==2.4


Although, I think I know a solution for those whose models can handle the change to the new tensorflow version.
I'd highly reccommend trying the following:
tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K
set_session = K.get_session

While using the latest tensorflow (which auto installs keras)
